# If statements in .htaccess files, to enable password protection when in specific directory only

Tags: svn, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 copies of my website synced with Subversion. One live version and one developer version. What I like to do is to password protect the developer version, using a .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
AuthPGAuthoritative Off
Require user dev
```

Is there a way to sync this .htaccess file to the live version without the password protection there?

I was thinking about something like

```
[if file exists ../.htpasswd]
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
  AuthPGAuthoritative Off
  Require user dev 
[/if]
```

or

```
[if currentDir = /path/to/dev/version]
...
[/if]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if statements are not supported.  Do you have access to the global apache config for your dev server?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143176/how-can-i-password-protect-dev-but-not-live-while-using-svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found the answer over here:
[How can I password protect dev but not live while using SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143176/how-can-i-password-protect-dev-but-not-live-while-using-svn)

If `mod_setenvif` is enabled one can set different env vars

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^HOST$ .+ unauthenticated
SetEnvIfNoCase ^HOST$ ^dev\.example\.com$ !unauthenticated
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. :)